# Wait for an observable to complete, start another, and subscribe to its output

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a function that will optionally set a header with data retrieved from `localStorage`. The `localStorage` operation returns a promise that I can turn into an Observable. Once the headers are set (or not), I want to make an http request and return the Observable as a result:

```
let startObs;
if (useHeaders) {
  startObs = Observable.fromPromise(this.getStoredHeaders());
}
else {
  startObs = Observable.empty();
}

// wait for startObs here

return this.http.get(url, headers);
```

Essentially I want to wait for `startObs` to complete and then return the `http.get` Observable. I have tried using something like `startObs.concat(this.http.get())` or `startObs.switch(this.http.get())`, but this emits from both the source observable and the `http.get` observable. I *only* want to emit the `http.get` Observable.

Is there any way to subscribe only to the last observable in a chain while waiting for a previous observable to complete?

Comment: where are you subscribing to the data? update that to post

Comment: It's async, that's the whole point of observables :) So you won't be able to accomplish that the way you want. You should subscribe and do what you want in that subscribe but subscribing in a service is not a good idea either. You should simply create the observable chain, and subscribe to it from a component for example

Comment: You can just use concat() then last(). http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-last

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve what you want with operators like `concat` and `switch`, because you'll still be calling the `this.http.get()` synchronously (before your stored headers are ready). Use `mergeMap` instead:

```
return startObs.mergeMap(headers => this.http.get(url, headers));
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an easy task for `concatMap`:

```
startObs
    .concatMap(() => this.http.get(url, headers))
    .subscribe(...);
```

Since it's supposed to map a value using a callback function you can simply ignore the value emitted from the source `startObs` and just return a new Observable.

You could also chain multiple `concatMap` operators because they only subscribe to the next Observable when the preceding one completes.